# bs4 scraping python get contents until specific class name

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to scrape this site
https://www.eduvision.edu.pk/institutions-detail.php?city=51I&institute=5_allama-iqbal-open-university-islamabad
and i want only the bachelor data in this url which is under class name=academicsList and i don't want below MS(MASTERS) data.
I want my scraper to stop before ms data. my logic is that we can set temporary incrementor on class=academicsHead and it should stop when it gets second academicsHead

```
   import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import  UserAgent
ua          = UserAgent()
header      = {'user-agent':ua.chrome}
response   = requests.get('https://www.eduvision.edu.pk/institutions-detail.php?city=51I&institute=5_allama-iqbal-open-university-islamabad',headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
disciplines = soup.findAll("ul", {"class": "academicsList"})
#temp = soup.findAll("ul",{"class":"academicsHead"})
#stop at second academicsHead
for d in disciplines:
    print(d.findAll('li')[0].text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can check if the class is 'academicsHead' and if it is just check if the text is BACHELOR if not break the loop.
Something like this would work:

```
disciplines = soup.findAll('ul',attrs={'class':re.compile(r'academics+(.)+')})

for i in disciplines:
    if i['class'][0] == 'academicsHead':
        if i.find('li').text.strip() != 'BACHELOR':
            break
    else:
        print(i.find('li').text.strip())
```